# Iframe scroll issue .. What is the solution?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I have two files on different servers, I am showing the data of one server into another using iframe, I am using below code

server.php (hosted on server A)

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
?>
this is itest
<div style="height:1100px; background-color:pink; width:100px" >sdfsd</div>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="goTop()">Go to Top</a>
<script>
function goTop () {
  parent.scrollTo(0,0);
}
</script>
```

---

client.php (hosted on server B)

```
<iframe src="http://serverA.com/server.php" height="1200px" >
```

---

When I click on "Go to Top"  link I get "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "...." from accessing a frame with origin "...". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. "

What is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a function in the parent frame that will scroll to the top (you have done this already in the form of `goTop`)
2. Use that function in an event listener for a `message` event on the `window` object
3. Use `parent.postMessage` from the document in the frame to send a message to the parent element

See [the MDN `postMessage` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) for examples.